# How to install numpy on Ubuntu in the correct way?

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, coredump

More than two weeks ago I tried to use `numpy` to find eigen vectors and eigen values of a 2 by 2 matrix. It did not work, I got `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`, message. I asked the question on stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206990/why-calculations-of-eigenvectors-of-a-2-by-2-matrix-with-numpy-crashes-my-python)).

The answer was that the syntax is correct and that I need to try a fresh installation and it has probably something to do with "SSE/SSE3-enabled binaries" (whatever it means).

Directed by these answer I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
virtualenv ~/python2/
source ~/python2/bin/activate
pip install numpy
python tmp.py
```

In my `tmp.py` I have:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la
w, v = la.eig(np.array([[1, -1], [1, 1]]))
```

As a result I got the same error message: `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

Does anybody know how python and numpy have to be installed to get it work?

**ADDED**

The following sequence does not resolve the problem:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade
virtualenv venv
~/venv/bin/activate
source ~/venv/bin/activate
pip install numpy
python tmp.py
```

Comment: SSE/SSE3 are CPU instruction sets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3. Your pip install numpy instruction had to output alot of 'gcc ...' log lines, can you upload it somewhere? This definetely has nothing to do with virtualenv and so on.

Comment: +1 to @alko suggestion of following seberg's comment on the original thread. Some versions of Ubuntu ship broken blas/lapack (I vaguely remember having problems with 64-bit lucid). At a barest minimum, run numpy.test() and see if there are fails around linalg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to make a try in a direction from original question comment, that is reinstall blas/lapack. See there for package names http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505249, and recompile numpy.

Answer (score 2):

```
>sudo pip install virtualenv
>sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade
>virtualenv venv
>. venv/bin/activate
>pip intsall <any package>
```

You need to upgrade the virtualenv

Comment: I performed the sequence of command that you gave. Unfortunately the original problem remain. I still have the same error message.